# how to use css-flip (bidi flipper) with node.js

Tags: node.js

Can any one please help me to get started with [css-flip](https://github.com/twitter/css-flip).

I have gone through their documentation but it seems to be for expert users. I do not have any experience with node.js.

How i will run the below CLI.

> css-flip path/to/file.css > path/to/file.rtl.css

Will be much thankful to any ones help.

Comment: What did you tried? What failed? Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install node.js and install the module globally with

```
npm install -g css-flip
```

Or

```
npm install -g git+https://github.com/twitter/css-flip.git
```

If you want to install from github.

You should then be able to run it from a command line.

```
css-flip in.css > out.css
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am facing this error
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ky7axzjnqknnh7f/flip.jpg

Comment: Looks like an error on their behalf, submit an issue to their github. Actually looks like they've fixed it in [this commit](https://github.com/twitter/css-flip/commit/89d1f21ef3107d7c610f205a5a4af6a957938f84) here, but haven't pushed it out to npm.

Comment: are to able to run it ? Did you download the master branch and copy pasted from  [here](https://github.com/twitter/css-flip/blob/89d1f21ef3107d7c610f205a5a4af6a957938f84/bin/css-flip) . It still gives error.

Comment: @codestings Try `npm -g rm css-flip` and then install from the git url above.

Comment: okay .. sorry can you explain how to install it . should i use "npm install -g css-flip" again.